# Why does sizeof() not return the length of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int test[3];
    int i;
    test[0]=5;
    test[1]=10;
    test[2]=7;

    printf("array size: %d\n",sizeof(test));
    sortArray(test);

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(test);i++) {
        printf(" %d ", test[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void sortArray(int number[]) {
    int i,j,a;
    int n = 5;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (number[j] < number[i]) {
                a = number[i];
                number[i] = number[j];
                number[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The array I am having problems with is "test"
When I run the program the "size" is always a multiple of 4 of the intended size. ex: test[3] would output a size of 12. What am I doing wrong? I am using code::blocks as an ide also.

Comment: `sortArray()` is accessing outside the array bounds. The array only has 3 elements, but you have `n = 5`.

Comment: however - do not be tempted to use sizeof inside sortArray. There is no way to find out from a passed pointer the size of the array behind it, you have to pass in the size as a parameter or have a sentinel value (-1, 0 9999, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sizeof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) returns the *memory size* of what you pass it. The return value is...

> measured in the number of char-sized storage units required for the
>   type

In a typical 32-bit system, a `char` is one byte and `int` is four bytes so you'll get a multiple of four for an array of type `int`.

If you'd like the *length* of the array, just divide by the size of the type:

```
int a[3];
size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Note: As [*dbush*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush) mentioned in the comments below:

> ...this only works if the array is not a paramerer to a
>   function. In that case the array decays to a pointer and sizeof(array)
>   evaluates to the size of a pointer.

Comment: Note that this only works if the array is *not* a paramerer to a function.  In that case the array decays to a pointer and `sizeof(array)` evaluates to the size of a pointer.

Comment: Thanks @dbush ! Updated the answer with that note

Comment: Thank you guys! I am new to C, so thanks for helping a newbie out!